# react-autosuggest with useRef

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create an input with the autosuggest. As I am using tailwind, there is no this kind of input there and therefore I came across react-autosuggest. The thing is however, I need to use a ref for this Autosuggest Input, cause I need to submit after a select and logically get the value of this Autosuggest Input on button click/submit. Here is part of my code (not everything). The code was working with normal input, so ne help needed apart from fixing the Ref problem:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';

    export const SearchBar = () => {
      const autosuggestInput = useRef(null);
      ....
      const city = autosuggestInput.current.value;
      ......
    return(
      <Autosuggest
         type="text"
         ref={autosuggestInput}
         className="py-3 px-4 block w-full shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 border-gray-300 rounded-md"
      />
    
    )
    }
```

Here I am getting the Error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. Which suggests that the ref is not working. I am using next.js and therefore also functional components. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: The initialValue of ref is null because of `useRef(null)`.

Comment: Du you really need to ref for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your ref line won't do anything. Because ref only applies  to the Host component, such as `div`, `p`, `button` etc.

```
  <div ref={ref}>ABC</div>
```

The above line will work. Ok, so in order to get the ref onto a custom component, there's some ways. One is to use a `forwardRef`, however either way the interface of `react-autosuggest` needs to allow you do that. I just read a bit, doesn't seem so.

However if you just want the value, seems the documentation is asking you do this

```
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'Type a programming language',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (
      <Autosuggest
        ...
        inputProps={inputProps}
      />
    );
```

Try their demo first. Basically any input is driven by `value` and `onChange`. The rest of them are all sugar code.

Answer (score 1):

React auto-suggest is a controlled component and so needs some mandatory parameters passed into it such as the value, suggestions, onChange handler etc. which is what is giving you the error and **NOT** useRef.

See **Basic Usage** here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autosuggest

[image]

The following props need to be passed through to the AutoSuggest component (From the Basic Usage npm docs) :

```
// Finally, render it!
return (
  <Autosuggest
    suggestions={suggestions}
    onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
    onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
    getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
    renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
    inputProps={inputProps}
  />
);
```